# Connect Mackie C1604VLZ-3 (passive mixer) to Phonic 620 Powerpod (powered) Mixer

Tags: mixer

I am using powered monitors with the Mackie and have no amplifier for 2 passive monitors. I do have another mixer that is powered that I would like to use however I need to be able to control the mix through the Mackie. I am not versed at all in this sort of thing and am worried I will destroy something if I hook it up incorrectly. Please advise in plain simple non gear head talk and assist me if you have any idea how to accomplish this.

Comment: The Mackie has a `tape out`, the Phonic has a `tape in` with its own level knob in the main section. That should be the easiest solution, and bypass any processing (except the main EQ) on the Phonic. Set all other inputs to minimum level to avoid hiss.

Comment: How many different monitor mixes do you need? If it's only the one, use the passive monitors as extension speakers from the powered monitors.Check impedances but generally if there's a speaker out on an active monitor, it's there for another speaker to be plugged in.

Comment: What is your application? I assumed you wanted to set up two sets of monitor speakers in your studio, @Tim seems to think this is for a live situation.

Answer (score 0):

To summarize:

You can plug the Mackie `tape out` into the Phonic `tape in` or:

If the impedances and resistances for the passive monitors match, then plug the passive monitors into the powered monitors' extension speaker jacks. Checking the impedances and resistance is very important because if they mismatch you could damage your speakers.

Answer (score 0):

Aux sends can be connected from the Mackie mixer to the Phonic's channel inputs.  If the Mackie's total output is needed to one channel, any of the line outs can be used to send a signal to one or more channels of the Phonic powered mixer. Choices are main outputs and monitor outputs from the Mackie.

The outputs are line level which is very compatible with various devices.  Turn all volumes/gains to zero, and EQs to middle. Make the connections using instrument cable (not speaker cable) then do a sound check by raising levels on the Mackie and the Phonic to balance output/input. Adjust EQs as needed on each mixer.